# Access and update the relationship field of a resource

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am grabbing the resource of particular asset from registry by something like this:-

```
 var  flight = factory.newResource(Namespace,'Aircraft',flightId);
```

To this resource, i am assigning a relationship by :-

```
 flight.aircraft = factory.newRelationship('org.acme.airline.aircraft','Aircraft',aircraftId); 

flight.aircraft.firstClassSeats = 10;

flight.aircraft.secondClassSeats = 10;
```

This relationship contains the following properties as defined in model file :

```
asset Aircraft identified by aircraftId {
  o String      aircraftId
  // Number of seats per class
  o Integer     firstClassSeats  default = 0  
  o Integer     businessClassSeats default = 0 
  o Integer     economyClassSeats    default = 0  
}
```

Flight Data :

```
asset Flight identified by flightId {


      o   String            flightId regex=/[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]/
      o   String            flightNumber
      o   Route             route
      o   String[]          aliasFlightNumber  optional
      --> Aircraft          aircraft  optional
    }
```

**Now, how to update these relationship values (for example firstClassSeats) of a particular flight resource and update it to the corresponding registry.**

Comment: I did not understand your question properly. You already have a relation defined between `flight` and `aircraft`. The `flight.aircraft` relation stores a relation and not the value at the time. Its similar to the difference between passing by value and by location. If you updated `firstClassSeats` and then query` flight.aircraft`, you will be returned the updated values.

Comment: I am assigning same aircraft to multiple flights here. So, if i update the firstClassSeats of a aircraft, the value of all flights which have relation with this aircraft, will get their firstClassSeats updated?

Comment: Yes they will get updated, based on the code posted above. If you could share the `Flight` code as well, I can confirm it. Best way to confirm yourself is upload the bna on composer playground. Should take you under 10-15min to install and run the scenario

Comment: I have added the flight data in the question. 
So, there is no way, i can access the values of assigned Aircraft relationship from the flight resource right?

Comment: Well if you have `--> Aircraft aircraft` as part of your data, then accessing it should give you the information you need.

Comment: Actually, i am facing problem with accessing the relationship fields. I have updated the question above. So, after assigining the values to the relationship and saving the flight resource to flight registry, when i try to access those fields in this manner : - flight.aircraft.firstClassSeats, i am always getting the result as undefined

Comment: flight.aircraft does not directly give access to field values of the aircraft resource

Comment: Please share the tx function where you are trying to get the values. I suspect a syntax issue cause your models look fine. Also you cannot do `flight.aircraft.firstClassSeats = 10;` afaik. You need to do `aircraft.firstClassSeats=10` and then update the aircraft state. The value of `flight.aircraft` will fetch the latest values on its own

Comment: Okay, now it makes sense. Thanks for the help!